# Failing to Bazel build C++ project with tensorflow as a dependency

Tags: c++, tensorflow, bazel

I see a lot of tutorials that explain how to build projects inside Tensorflow's Bazel WORKSPACE (like [this one](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/extend/cc)). But I can't seem to be able to find a way to build my own project and include tensorflow as a dependency. I looked at [this](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/external.html#bazel-projects) Bazel documentation, and there is clearly a way to build with external dependencies, which I tried to follow myself. (since tf is also built with bazel).

Here is what my directory structure looks like:

```
.
├── perception
│   ├── BUILD
│   └── graph_loader.cc
├── third-party
│   └── tensorflow # I cloned tf repo into this folder
└── WORKSPACE
```

Here is what's inside my `perception/BUILD` file:

```
cc_binary(
    name = "graph-loader",
    srcs = [
        "graph_loader.cc",
    ],
    deps = [
        "@tensorflow//tensorflow:libtensorflow.so",
    ]
)
```

Here is what's inside my `WORKSPACE` file:

```
local_repository(
    name = "tensorflow",
    path = "path/to/my/project/third-party/tensorflow",
)
```

Here is what's inside my `perception/graph_loader.cc` file:

```
#include "tensorflow/cc/client/client_session.h"
#include "tensorflow/cc/ops/standard_ops.h"
#include "tensorflow/core/framework/tensor.h"

int main() {
  using namespace tensorflow;
  using namespace tensorflow::ops;
  Scope root = Scope::NewRootScope();
  // Matrix A = [3 2; -1 0]
  auto A = Const(root, { {3.f, 2.f}, {-1.f, 0.f} });
  // Vector b = [3 5]
  auto b = Const(root, { {3.f, 5.f} });
  // v = Ab^T
  auto v = MatMul(root.WithOpName("v"), A, b, MatMul::TransposeB(true));
  std::vector<Tensor> outputs;
  ClientSession session(root);
  // Run and fetch v
  TF_CHECK_OK(session.Run({v}, &outputs));
  // Expect outputs[0] == [19; -3]
  LOG(INFO) << outputs[0].matrix<float>();
  return 0;
}
```

I run my build with the following command:

```
build //perception:graph-loader
```

But it fails with this message:

```
ERROR: path/to/my/project/perception/BUILD:1:1: error loading package '@tensorflow//tensorflow': Extension file not found. Unable to load package for '@local_config_cuda//cuda:build_defs.bzl': The repository could not be resolved and referenced by '//perception:graph-loader'
ERROR: Analysis of target '//perception:graph-loader' failed; build aborted: error loading package '@tensorflow//tensorflow': Extension file not found. Unable to load package for '@local_config_cuda//cuda:build_defs.bzl': The repository could not be resolved
INFO: Elapsed time: 0.037s
INFO: 0 processes.
FAILED: Build did NOT complete successfully (1 packages loaded, 0 targets configured)
    currently loading: @tensorflow//tensorflow
```

Here are the quesitions:

1. What am I doing wrong so that my build keeps failing?
2. Is it even possible to do what I'm trying here, i.e. build tensorflow inside of my project?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are getting this error because you have not added the required repository rules in your `WORKSPACE`. Bazel currently does not have recursive workspace, so you need to manually copy those repositories of all your dependencies into the main `WORKSPACE`.

In your `WORKSPACE` file, copy this:

```
local_repository(
    name = "org_tensorflow",
    path = "third-party/tensorflow",
)
```

Append all content of https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/WORKSPACE into the `WORKSPACE` file. Remove the `workspace(name = "org_tensorflow")` line.

Finally, change all `//*` in `WOKRSPACE` to `@org_tensorflow//*`.

Note that building Tensorflow in sub-folder is not officially supported.

Comment: Wow, your help was amazing. Everything works now! Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

John London's answer may be reasonable if you can use a subfolder.

In some cases you will prefer to use an external dependency, and this is still a bit difficult to set up.  See the [TensorFlow Serving repo](https://github.com/tensorflow/serving)'s setup for an example of a project that manages to do this.  Due to the bazel restrictions, you will need to copy the contents of the `WORKSPACE` and possibly `.bazelrc` into your own repo's.

This will suffice for some cases but not all.  If you are using rules defined within the @org_tensorflow repo (e.g. such as tfcompile's `tf_library()`), the dependencies defined by those rules may need to be redefined within your repo's .bzl to have `@org_tensorflow//` in front of them.